# How can I substract the value from this type of data?

Tags: r

The data set can be found here - gss.norc.org/Documents/spss/2018_spss.zip

```
class(GSS2018$ABFELEGL[2])

[1] "haven_labelled" "vctrs_vctr"     "double"
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to be certain without seeing the rest of you code but may help:

```
# treat labeled field as numeric and subtract 1
thingy =<- as.numeric(GSS2018$ABFELEGL[2]) - 1
```